# Attaching a Mottie virtual keyboard to a ajaxcontroltoolkit combobox

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, combobox

I am trying to get a Mottie virtual keyboard to display when I type into an ajaxcontroltoolkit combobox anyone out there have any experience with this?  I do not have a lot of experience with javascript/jquery.

I am trying to do this in ASP.NET webform

I have all the js libraries installed and it will work on a regular textbox or input field but I just don't know how to hook it up to the combobox or if it can be done.

here is a piece of script I am working on:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#ComboBox1').keyboard({
                usePreview: false,
                autoAccept: true,
                enterNavigation: true,
                visible: function (e, keyboard, el) {
                    keyboard.$keyboard.prepend('<h2/>')
                        .draggable({
                            handle: "h2",
                            containment: "window"
                        });
                }
            })
            .addTyping();
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because the `ComboBox` created by the ASP.NET AJAX Control Toolkit outputs an HTML like this:

```
<div id="ComboBox1" style="display:inline-block;">
  <table id="ComboBox1_Table" class="ajax__combobox_inputcontainer" style="border-width:0px;border-style:None;border-collapse:collapse;display:inline-block;position:relative;top:5px;" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td class="ajax__combobox_textboxcontainer"><input style="margin: 0px;" name="ctl00$ComboBox1$TextBox" id="ComboBox1_TextBox" autocomplete="off" type="text"></td>
        <td class="ajax__combobox_buttoncontainer"><button id="ComboBox1_Button" type="button" style="visibility: visible; height: 23px; width: 23px; margin: 0px; padding: 0px;"></button></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <input name="ctl00$ComboBox1$HiddenField" id="ComboBox1_HiddenField" value="0" type="hidden">
</div>
```

The `input[type=text]` generated has a different ID. It concatenates the server's ID with `_Textbox`.

So, in your case you must use `$('#ComboBox1_TextBox').keyboard` to make it works. E.g:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#ComboBox1_TextBox').keyboard({
                usePreview: false,
                autoAccept: true,
                enterNavigation: true,
                visible: function (e, keyboard, el) {
                    keyboard.$keyboard.prepend('<h2/>')
                        .draggable({
                            handle: "h2",
                            containment: "window"
                        });
                }
            })
            .addTyping();
    });
</script>
```

Comment: That worked mostly, now the issue is after the combobox looses focus and if I go back to it the virtual keyboard doesn't show up again.  Thank you Buzinas for getting me this far!